# Angular - Check multiple Child components form as dirty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

I have some bunch of child components holding a `form` - value for the form will be send from the parent components - i have looped the child components in the parent and passed the data to the components

**Child Component**

```
<form #formType="ngForm">
    <div class="col-lg-4" *ngFor="let data of productSizes; let i = index;">
        <div class="inlinediv" *ngFor="let item of data.ItemDetails">
            <div class="marginright15 inlinediv">
                <ng-container *ngIf="item.Foundation">
                    <b>{{item.Size.toUpperCase()}}</b><br />
                    <input *ngFor="let val of item.Foundation" type="text" appNumbericInput maxlength="4" [(ngModel)]="val.Val" class="inputcustom text-right" [disabled]="(val.Val == null ? true : false) || disableChecker" (input)="enableSave=true" />
                </ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Child Component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-base-mattress',
    templateUrl: './base-mattress.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./base-mattress.component.css']
})

export class BaseMattressComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() productSizes: IItemDetails[];
    @ViewChild('formType') formVariable: NgForm;
    blobURL: string = environment.blobURL;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**Parent Component html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let slot of slotRequests; let j = index;">
    <ng-container *ngIf="slot.ItemGrouping.toLowerCase() === 'mattress'">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let data of slotRequests[j].Data; let i = index;">
            <app-base-mattress [productSizes]="data"></app-base-mattress>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Now my problem is that i want to read the child component form variable? 
I don't want a service to subscribe and check whether the `form` dirty, i have tried it many times it doesn't work.

I have tried to map my child with template reference variable like this 
`<app-base-mattress [productSizes]="data" #childData></app-base-mattress>`
but it seems I'm looping the child component so it doesn't seem to act as an reference variable for specific component - Please help me to find out how can i read the child component form variable

Working version of my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxsehj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: do you want to access form value from parent?

Comment: Yes - i want to check whether the form is dirty and do some actions from it

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Comment: I have added the stackblitz version @Chellappan - please check

Comment: Why would observable not work? I have a belief, it should. Create the observable in the service and trigger it on form dirty action from the child component with unique ID of the component to differentiate. Though I also think this will complicate the app

Comment: Yeah it might work - its a case that child components are direct children to the parent why should i go for service instead of reading the child in the parent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use form element in your top level component

```
<form #formType="ngForm">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let slot of slotRequests; let j = index;">
        <ng-container *ngIf="slot.ItemGrouping.toLowerCase() === 'mattress'">
            <ng-container>

                <div *ngFor="let data of slotRequests[j].Data; let i = index;">
                    <app-base-mattress [productSizes]="data.ItemDetails"></app-base-mattress>
                </div>

            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

Use viewproviders to provide controncontainer which is super class for formDirectives the use existing ngForm group group together your form

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-mattress',
  templateUrl: './base-mattress.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base-mattress.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]
})
export class BaseMattressComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() productSizes: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ch5yh2

Comment: Thanks @erdalprinz gald to help. 

Comment: This works but it doesn't use slot 1 for slot 1 it just uses the last item in the data array.  Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**parent.component.html**:

```
<app-base-mattress #childCmp [productSizes]="data"></app-base-mattress>
```

**parent.component.ts**:

```
@ViewChildren('childCmp ')
childCmps: QueryList<BaseMattressComponent>;
```

and then iterate through them to achieve desired results

```
this.childCmps.forEach((item) => {
...
});
```

Comment: Good answer - but i want only the components whose form is dirty - do i need to loop through each component to check whether it's dirty ?

Comment: If you want to work with them as with variables then you should iterate through all of them.

p.s. In some cases it may be helpful to add unique ids to `<app-base-mattress`